# Give rsyslog read access to all log files that I want to monitor

Tags: logging, rsyslog

I'm using the $InputFile facility in rsyslog to monitor various log files scattered around my ubuntu 12.04 server. E.g. nginx, unicorn, rails, postgres, cron etc. Now my problem is, that some of these log files are created with -rw-r----- right, so rsyslog doesn't have read rights. Since I install most of the programs using apt-get, and therefore didn't change anything from default. So, in other words, I would like not to modify every singe log file / daemon to have the right permissions, if I instead could give syslog read access to all of them at once. But the question is - can I do that, and is it the "right thing to do"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change rsyslog's permission in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

from:

```
$PrivDropToGroup syslog
```

to

```
$PrivDropToGroup adm
```

or other group that can access those log files.

Answer (score 0):

As -rw-r----- is giving a read access to the owning group, you should add "syslog" user to that related group.